# Merge Unknown number of objects in array into single js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have an object as follows

```
[
    {
        "config": {
            "holes": 18
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "single_cart": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "shared_cart": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "caddie": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "transfers": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "meals": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "all_inclusive": false
        }
    }
]
```

which i am trying to convert into

```
{
   "config":{
      "holes":18,
      "single_cart":false,
      "shared_cart":false,
      "caddie":false,
      "transfers":false,
      "meals":false,
      "all_inclusive":false
   }
}
```

This is an example 'merge' as these could be of any name and value key. I have tried and failed to use reduce, map, foreach and can never join them together as such.

If someone can help point me in the right direction that would be amazing.  All the examples i have seen refer to specifically named keys to do the merge using object.assign etc..

Comment: Could `"config"` be named anything or just the properties within?

Comment: Config can be named Anything, so i don't think everyone read the last paragraph of my request

Comment: I've posted an answer that should work without knowing any of the keys (including "config") in advance. Let me know if it does the trick or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without knowing any of the keys in advance.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "config": {
      "holes": 18
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "single_cart": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "shared_cart": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "caddie": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "transfers": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "meals": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "all_inclusive": false
    }
  }
];

const mergeObjects = (a, b) => {
  for (let k in b) {
    if (k in a) {
      if (typeof(a[k]) === 'object' && typeof(b[k]) === 'object') {
        a[k] = mergeObjects(a[k], b[k]);
      } else {
        throw `Unable to merge because key "${k}" is in both objects (and not both values are objects).`;
      }
    } else {
      a[k] = b[k];
    }
  }

  return a;
};

const output = input.reduce(mergeObjects, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to merge all the objects in the array. You can use `...` spread syntax to combine objects.

```js
const data = [{
    "config": {
      "holes": 18
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "single_cart": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "shared_cart": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "caddie": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "transfers": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "meals": false
    }
  },
  {
    "config": {
      "all_inclusive": false
    }
  }
];

const result = {
  config: data.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, ...obj.config}), {})
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This would work if i knew the dimensions of the object each time.

Comment: I thought you were referring to the nested keys like `holes` and `single_cart`. I assumed `config` was known, since it's consistent throughout the example.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a one-liner:

```js
let data = [ 
    {
        "config": {
            "holes": 18
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "single_cart": false
        }
    },
    /* more of your data.... */ 
]

const result = data.reduce((prev, {config}) => ({config: {...prev.config, ...config}}), {config: {}})
```

You can use `reduce` to flatten arrays or to create objects. You don't even need to declare a separate variable to assign your data to.

If you have a default config or previous data, you want to override, you can change the second parameter of the reduce function:

```js
const defaultConfig = {
    config: {
      "holes": 0,
      "single_cart": true,
    }
}

const newConfig = data.reduce((prev, {config}) => ({config: {...prev.config, ...config}}), defaultConfig)
```

See more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

I created a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/richardtknight/pen/XWqpzyX)

which does what you were looking for in a fairly simple way.

```
const data = [
    {
        "config": {
            "holes": 18
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "single_cart": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "shared_cart": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "caddie": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "transfers": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "meals": false
        }
    },
    {
        "config": {
            "all_inclusive": false
        }
    }
]

const obj = { 
  config: {} 
}

data.forEach((row) => {
  obj.config[Object.keys(row.config)[0]] = row.config[Object.keys(row.config)[0]];
})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Why use an external codepen when you can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) here?